# are there any tools that check the quality of javaDoc (phpDoc, etc.) automatically?

Tags: javadoc, phpdoc

Do you know any tools that can run through the code and find defects in javaDoc blocks? (would be nice to parse other languages also, like PHP, C#, etc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) reports errors in the documentation. Depending on how it is configured it can also report when documentation is missing.

A similar question (but not exactly the same): [Is there a way to validate the presence of Javadoc and/or inline code comments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580215/is-there-a-way-to-validate-the-presence-of-javadoc-and-or-inline-code-comments/2580312)

Answer (score 2):

PHPDocumentor will give you a list of errors, in the case of phpDoc.

Comment: Could you please explain how exactly I can get a list of errors with phpDoc? I can't find this in their documentation. Thanks!

Comment: I believe it actually makes a errors.html file. Also, when I run it, it spits out tons of warnings for me. By default it also displays them in the console, unless -quiet is used.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started a open source JavaDoc checking utility: [OpenJavaDocCheck](http://github.com/egonw/ojdcheck). The project is fairly young, but some features are:

- XHTML+RDFa output (or just XML, so that you can use XSLT to create whatever)
- extensible (to test for project specific JavaDoc patterns, such as custom tags)